# Making sane changes in files without opening them in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have some XML files.

Presently an attribute `envid` is set to `null` and I want it to be `QA` in all the file(s). How can i do that without opening each and every file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i 's:envid="":envid="QA":g' *.xml
```

Should replace every occurence of `envid=""` with `envid="QA"` in your `*.xml` files. But don't forget that XML files can be strangly formatted, e.g. this won't be replaced:

```
<tag envid=''>
```

neither this

```
<tag envid=
     "">
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by opening? To change a file, you have to open it, but probably by a different program than your text editor. For example:

```
sed -i~ 's/envid="null"/envid="QA"/g' *.xml
```

It should replace all strings `envid="null"` with `envid="QA"` in your xml files, leaving a backup with the `~` suffix. The `g` is needed if several substituions are needed on one line.

Be careful when changing xml this way, though. If any of the xml files contains the string `envid="null"` somewhere (attibute xenvid, text inside an element), the script will replace it as well. For safety, I'd use something like [xsh](http://search.cpan.org/~pajas/XML-XSH2-2.1.5/lib/XML/XSH2.pm):

```
xsh 'for //@envid[.="null"] set . "QA" ; save :b' -F *.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough context to give you an exact answer. However, try to get inspiration from:

```
perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/g' *.xml
```